# Referencing a form element by name

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Windows Form Application in Visual C# 2010.

I have twenty buttons named button1,...,button20 and twenty labels named label1,...,label20. How do I change the text of label1 in response to a click on button1, and similarly with each button-label pair without having 20 separate event handler functions?

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET? …?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  When asking a question please be sure to include tags that specify the context of the problem.  In this case, we need to know what type of technology to use so that the answer is geared for said application.

Answer (score 7):

For the love of god why!!!

But really you could use a dictionary keyed to the button, for example:

```
Dictionary<Button,Label> dict = new Dictionary<Button,Label>();

    dict.Add(button1,label1);
    ...
```

Then you can just do:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = dict[(Button)sender];
    label.Text = "Hello";
}
```

All buttons can then use the same click handler.

You could also similarly use `Button.Tag` and have that point to each label.

However, I think the better solution would be to develop a custom UserControl that shrink wraps your button and label into one neat package.

Answer (score 1):

When you're going to be using a grouping of controls over and over, it's easier to make a custom user control that incorporates them together.

So in this case, create a new user control with a label and a button. In the button's onclick handler, change label.Text to whatever you want it to be. Build your project.

Add the newly created user control to your main form 20 times. Since the buttons are already associated with their respective labels, you don't need to have separate handlers for each and every one of them.

(Keep in mind that you now have 20 controls named userControl1, userControl2, etc... so if you need to do anything else with their inner contents you'll need to do additional processing. For the sake of this example though, you don't have to worry about this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe all events to one handler and check first argument 'sender'. Sender should be the button, you can check its ID.

Comment: Then how do you find the label that corresponds to the button?